# Getting the parameters of a generic type into a dictionary

Tags: c#, performance, linq, generics, reflection

I have written a method which iterates over the generic parameter types of an instance...

`Dictionary<string, Guid>` **returns**

> TKey: System.String
>
> TValue: System.Guid

`Tuple<Guid, bool, StringBuilder>` **returns**

> T1: System.Guid
>
> T2: System.Boolean
>
> T3: System.Text.StringBuilder

**Method**

```
public static Dictionary<String, Type> GetGenericParameters(Type type)
{
    Dictionary<string, Type> result = new Dictionary<string, Type>();
    Type[] tValues = type.GetGenericArguments();
    Type[] tKeys = type.GetGenericTypeDefinition().GetGenericArguments();
    if (tValues.Length == tKeys.Length)
    {
        for (int index = 0; index < tValues.Length; index++)
        {
            result.Add(tKeys[index].Name, tValues[index]);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

**Test:**

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Type> pair in GetGenericParameters(typeof(Tuple<string, int, Guid, StringBuilder, long, bool, Tuple<bool, string>>)))
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", pair.Key, pair.Value);
}
```

**Result:**

> T1: System.String
>
> T2: System.Int32
>
> T3: System.Guid
>
> T4: System.Text.StringBuilder
>
> T5: System.Int64
>
> T6: System.Boolean
>
> T7: System.Tuple`2[System.Boolean,System.String]

It seems to work ok...but my gut feeling is that there will be cases where this logic will be broken, and could likely be written to be more efficient...possibly with linq or something...any ideas on how I can improve this and ensure it doesn't break?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: What you're doing is essentially correct. You could use `Zip` to correlate the type arguments from the type definition and the contstructed type. Also, putting them into a Dictionary is counter-productive if you intend to iterate over them in the correct order.

Comment: @GertArnold - please feel free to migrate it there if that is where it belongs, and you have the necessary powers.

Comment: @Avish - I guess I just feel that it's a dirty solution overall...I'm sure there must be a cleaner way to achieve this using reflection, and what is already available in the framework. But thank you for your notes on using a Dictionary and iteration order - I may change the implementation to use List<KeyValuePair<string, Type>> or something to that effect.